# Limiting apps limits other apps too

Tags: settings

I'm trying to limit apps for my son (who has a separate standard user account) and when I add Firefox, it automatically adds a bunch of other apps (the Libre office suite, VLC, audacity etc) that I would like him to have access to. I've tried doing it several times. Even if I simply go to settings on my (administrator) account, then add firefox to the listed apps (under "prevent user from using these apps") or delete the apps I want him to have access to, then close the window, when I open the settings window again, the other apps are there again.

I'm using Elementary os 7.1 Horus, installed a few days ago.

I have some experience with Linux, but trying to change anything in code is not something I would be comfortable with. If there is a setting I can tweak, a terminal command I can use (the full command or string of commands would be best) or something user-friendly, that would be best. Thank you!